# create ip external valid in the network interface

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am buying a software, but the distributor said that it needs the valid ip configured in the network interfaces, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? Do they required a valid, internet-routable IP in ifconfig? Or do they just want to know which internet IP your host is using?

Comment: thanks for the return, they want a valid ip in ifconfig, so I've been searching it's not possible even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software vendor requires a public IP address to be bound to your VM instance, the answer is that this is not possible.

In Google (and AWS, Azure, etc), public IP addresses are not bound to the Ethernet interfaces on the VM instance. The public IP address is assigned to the public side of a 1-to-1 NAT gateway. This gateway does the translation from a public IP address to the private IP address that is assigned to your VM instance.

Share this information with the software vendor. As the cloud grows in popularity, they will need to find another way to authorize their licenses.

Answer (score 0):

thanks john for the return, they want a valid ip in VM instance, license issue, I think it is tied by mac. As I do not have the advanced support ($ 200.00) you in the community are invaluable in helping us. Thank you very much, I will be passing the information to the supplier. I researched google doc and they had not posted anything about it, at least I did not find it.